# Lumen validation will not specify what fields have failed

Tags: php, laravel, api, lumen

I'm trying to include validation in my Lumen API, however I'm having some difficulty with the response when validation fails:

**BooksController.php**

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    $this->validateBook($request);

    $book = Book::create($request->all());
    $data = $this->item($book, new BookTransformer());

    return response()->json($data, 201, [
      'Location' => route('books.show', ['id' => $book->id]),
    ]);
  }

  private function validateBook(Request $request)
  {
    $this->validate($request, [
      'title'       => 'required|max:255',
      'description' => 'required',
      'author_id'   => 'required|exists:authors,id',
    ], [
      'description.required' => 'Please fill out the description.',
    ]);
  }
```

I've modified my handler to to check for an instance of ValidationException, but for whatever reason my response is always the same...

**Handler.php**

```
  public function render($request, Exception $e)
  {
    if ($request->wantsJson()) {
      $response = [
        'message' => (string) $e->getMessage(),
        'status'  => 400,
      ];

      if ($e instanceof HttpException) {
        $response['message'] = Response::$statusTexts[$e->getStatusCode()];
        $response['status']  = $e->getStatusCode();
      } else if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        $response['message'] = Response::$statusTexts[Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND];
        $response['status']  = Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND;
      } else if ($e instanceof ValidationException) {

        // [BUG] Shouldn't this display the fields that have failed?
        $response['message'] = 'how do I display what fields failed?'; 
        $response['status']  = Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY;        

      }

      if ($this->isDebugMode()) {
        $response['debug'] = [
          'exception' => get_class($e),
          'trace'     => $e->getTrace(),
        ];
      }

      return response()->json(['error' => $response], $response['status']);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);

  }
```

If I remove the block of code that checks for an instead of `ValidationException` my response is always the same:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "The given data failed to pass validation.",
    "status": 400
  }
}
```

However, this will prove to be a nightmare for anyone on the client-side who's trying to interface with the API as it does not specify anything about what fields failed and does not include my custom error messages.

I'm expecting something more like:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "The given data failed to pass validation.",
    "errors": {
         "title": "The title is required.",
         "description": "Please fill out the description."
     },
    "status": 422
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I needed to let the parent handler take care of the error response instead of checking for an instance of ValidationException and returning my own custom response.  The revised code is as follows:

**Handler.php**

```
  public function render($request, Exception $e)
  {
    if ($request->wantsJson() && !($e instanceof ValidationException)) {
      $response = [
        'message' => (string) $e->getMessage(),
        'status'  => 400,
      ];

      if ($e instanceof HttpException) {
        $response['message'] = Response::$statusTexts[$e->getStatusCode()];
        $response['status']  = $e->getStatusCode();
      } else if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        $response['message'] = Response::$statusTexts[Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND];
        $response['status']  = Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND;
      }

      if ($this->isDebugMode()) {
        $response['debug'] = [
          'exception' => get_class($e),
          'trace'     => $e->getTrace(),
        ];
      }

      return response()->json(['error' => $response], $response['status']);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only the validation field errors, you can take it from the content of getResponse method. The result a json string so you need to json_decode it

```
public function render($request, exception $e)
{
    $rendered = parent::render($request, $e);
    $statusCode = $rendered->getstatuscode();
    $errorResponse = [
        'error' => true,
        'code' => $statusCode,
        'message' => $e->getmessage(),
    ];
    if ($e instanceof ValidationException) {
        $errorResponse['message'] = json_decode($e->getResponse()->content());
    }
    return response()->json($errorResponse, $statusCode);
}
```